# Assignment without copy in std move

Tags: c++, c++11, move, rvo, nrvo

I have a util function which returns a map

```
std::map getFooMap() {
  std::map foo;
  // ... populate the map
  return foo;
}
```

From the caller side, I want to assign the map to a data field of some object. I can do:

```
dest.data = getFooMap()
```

Will this be faster than the following?

```
auto temp = getFooMap();
dest.data = std::move(temp);
```

I think this should be as I avoid one extra copy?

Comment: Good compiler will optimise both calls to do virtually the same, although if that won't be the case, the first one is preferred. Why would you want to name the returned variable just to `std::move` it immediately?

Comment: Have you examined the assembly? FWIW, I heard `std::move` inhibits [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), so on a good compiler I'd expect the move-less option to be faster or at least as fast as the one with `std::move`.

Comment: It would be best if you managed to _construct_ `dest.data` with a `getFooMap()` call, which usually means making the call when `dest` is constructed. Is that possible for you?

Answer (score 2):

> I think this should be as I avoid one extra copy?

As long as the "`std::map`" is movable, you're only potentially avoiding one extra move - which the optimizer may avoid just as well.

Performance difference is probably negligible or nonexistent, but `dest.data = getFooMap()` is simpler and likely to not be slower.

As pointed out in a comment, it would be even faster to directly initialise the `dest.data` instead of assigning it after construction. This can be achieved by calling `getFooMap` in a member initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

From an aesthetic perspective, it *has* to be the first variant. You must have some faith in the language standard and in the compiler authors to not require a silly artifact like a temporary to facilitate optimizations here.

Let's check if this is indeed the case. First, allow me to abstract your example somewhat and replace `map` with a class `foo`, without defining its various methods; and to assume nothing throws any exceptions:

```
#include <utility>

// Originally this was an std::map, replaced with
// an "opaque" class to shorten the output and
//  prevent inlining and conflation of 
// std-map-related code with the rest of the code
struct foo {
    foo() noexcept;
    foo(const foo&) noexcept;
    foo(foo&&) noexcept;
    foo& operator=(foo&&) noexcept;
    foo& operator=(const foo&) noexcept;
    ~foo() noexcept;
};

struct dest_t { foo data; };

foo get_foo() noexcept;
void do_stuff_with(const dest_t& dest) noexcept;

void move_from_intermediate() noexcept {
    dest_t dest;
    auto temp = get_foo();
    dest.data = std::move(temp);
    do_stuff_with(dest);
}

void straight_assignment() noexcept {
    dest_t dest;
    dest.data = get_foo();
    do_stuff_with(dest);
}
```

Now, if we [compile this on GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/gdZUw9) we see that GCC (trunk) produces the same assembly code for both functions. That includes:

- 1 construction
- 2 destructions
- 1 move assignment
- 1 call to `get_foo()`
- 1 call to `do_stuff_with()`

in both cases. clang (trunk) will also produce the same code as well, up to slight reordering - but not exactly the same code as GCC.